# Mysql search for specific on criterias

Tags: mysql

I am coding mysql in rstudio and I want to find a row which shows minimum weight_g(weight in grams). Then I use a below command but it shows errors.

> Q("select * from bl where Weight_g = min(Weight_g)")
>   [1] "HY000 1111 [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.17-log]Invalid use of group function"
>   [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select * from bl where Weight_g = min(Weight_g)'"

I am stuck with this error message and any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Change "= min(Weight_g)"  in "in (select min(Weight_g) from bl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this without duplicates:

```
select * 
from bl 
ORDER BY Weight_g ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Or these to get all the different instances with minimum weights:

```
select A.*
from bl A
where 
A.weight_g=(select weight_g from bl ORDER BY weight_g ASC
LIMIT 1);
```

Or:

```
select A.*
from bl A
where 
A.weight_g=(select min(weight_g) from bl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the minimum value inside subquery,

```
select * 
from bl 
where Weight_g = (SELECT min(Weight_g) from bl)
```

if you don't care about duplicate and wanted to get only one value, then `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` will suffice,

```
select * 
from bl 
ORDER BY Weight_g ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: There is a synthax error in your second query, remove the where clause.